# how to improve tesseract-OCR for this image

Tags: image, image-processing, python-tesseract

In reality I have a simple image but the result is always very bad. I tried to binarize but tesseract-OCR should already do it. One result is for example:

'T MRR F  4 4 G 0 4 2 3 0 0 G'.

The image is:

[image]

The original is:
[image]

Comment: Show us the original image.

Comment: By the way, the results aren't bad at all. The I is dropped and the 1's are consistently confused with 4. The rest is perfect.